# envio de email com phpmailer

Tags: php, sql-server, phpmailer

Olá.

Tenho uma consulta(SQLSRV) que me trás uma lista de clientes com os títulos financeiros vencidos. Tenho que mandar um e-mail(PHPMAILER) para cada um com seus títulos vencidos em aberto.
Como estou fazendo, consigo mandar um e-mail a cada linha, então seguindo a tabela abaixo, o esperado é que eu envie UM e-mail para cliente1 com os dois valores do mesmo, e um e-mail para o cliente2 com os dois valores do mesmo.

Como eu trataria este caso ?

| Cliente | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| cliente1 | valor1 |
| cliente1 | valor2 |
| cliente2 | valor3 |
| cliente2 | valor4 |

Saída de valores da consulta:

```
$vencimentos = $query->fetchAll();
$content =
'<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nro. Nota</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Emissão</th>
      <th>Parcela</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';
    foreach($vencimentos as $v){
      $name = $v["A1_NOME"];
      $email = $v["A1_EMAIL"];
      $content .= 
      '<tr>
        <td>'.$v["E1_NUM"].'</td>
        <td>'.$v["A1_NOME"].'</td>
        <td>'.$v["E1_EMISSAO"].'</td>
        <td>'.$v["E1_PARCELA"].'</td>
        <td>'.number_format($v["E1_VALOR"], 2, ",", "") .'</td>
      </tr>';
    }
$content .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $content;
die;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada você precisa agrupar os títulos por cliente, algo como:

```php
$vencimentosPorCliente = [];

foreach ($vencimentos as $vencimento) {
    $vencimentosPorCliente[$vencimento["A1_EMAIL"]][] = $vencimento;
}
```

Tendo os títulos agrupados você pode construir uma `<table>` para cada cliente e enviá-la para o respectivo e-mail, algo como:

```php
foreach ($vencimentosPorCliente as $cliente => $vencimentos) {
    $content = '<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Nro. Nota</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Emissão</th>
            <th>Parcela</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

    foreach ($vencimentos as $vencimento) {
        $content .= '<tr>
            <td>' . $vencimento["E1_NUM"] . '</td>
            <td>' . $vencimento["A1_NOME"] . '</td>
            <td>' . $vencimento["E1_EMISSAO"] .'</td>
            <td>' . $vencimento["E1_PARCELA"] . '</td>
            <td>' . number_format($vencimento["E1_VALOR"], 2, ",", "") . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }

    $content .= '</tbody></table>';

    // enviarEmail($cliente, $content);
}
```

Veja [um exemplo funcional](https://phpsandbox.io/n/lively-firefly-1eee-pqobl)

Comment: Olá Daniel, fiz exatamente como sua dica no exemplo e deu super certo, obrigado pela ajuda.